# Nix shell with customized dependencies

Tags: nix

I now understand how to write a basic `shell.nix`
the a project that I am developing.
I have something like this:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ 
    cmake
    boost
    eigen
  ];
}
```

There is, however, one more package
(e.g., `cln`)
this project depends on
that I need to download
the source from a git repository
and compile with some special flags.
The package uses `autoconf`,
and I simply need to enable/disable a few options.
I am not sure how to achieve this in this `shell.nix`.
The following is my current attempt,
which I piece together from various google searches.
It does not work, and I have no clue how to fix it
(or how to search for help):

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {    # this line causes an error
  name = "cln-m1";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "https://www.ginac.de/CLN/cln-1.3.6.tar.bz2";
  };    # I also want to pass some flags to "configure" here
}

pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ 
    cmake
    boost
    eigen
    cln-m1    # this is the customized package I want to add
  ];
}
```

This code does not work as
the `stdenv.mkDerivation...` line produces the error:

> error: attempt to call something which is not a function but a set

I would like to fix that and be able to pass some flags into the `configure` script of `cln`
before building it
and use the customized `cln` (`cln-m1`)
as the dependency for this shell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let's break it up into two parts.  First, write a `cln.nix` that you can build with `nix-build cln.nix` that builds the software you are interested in.  If it succeeds, it will make a `result` symlink in your current directory and you can inspect the result and try running it to make sure it's OK.  Then write a `shell.nix` that has an `import` statement to import cln.nix and add it to the `nativeBuildInputs` list.  Which of those two steps are you struggling with and what is the specific part you are getting stuck on?

Comment: You're getting the error message "attempt to call something which is not a function" because you're just slapping unrelated bits of code together in the same file without a concept of how the Nix language syntax works.  Recommended reading:  https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/index.html   Specifically, when you write "A B" Nix usually assumes A is a function and B is an argument to it, so it thinks you are trying to pass your `pkgs.mkShell` stuff as an argument to the stuff that came before it, which is not even a function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's like basic functional programming.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  cln-m1 = stdenv.mkDerivation {    # this line causes an error
    name = "cln-m1";
    src = fetchurl {
      url = "https://www.ginac.de/CLN/cln-1.3.6.tar.bz2";
    };    # I also want to pass some flags to "configure" here
  };

in pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ 
    cmake
    boost
    eigen
    cln-m1    # this is the customized package I want to add
  ];
}
```

Comment: I mean, this is just showing the composition part.  Here I'm not trying to address how to write packages, i.e. stdenv.mDerivation and all contained inside its call - that's unrelated to nix-shell.